# docusign checkbox value based on API call not working

Tags: checkbox, docusignapi

I am trying to pass selected checkbox values from a real estate contract via the REST API. Currently I am able to make the check boxes show up on the document but they do not show checked or uncheck based on the True/False data passed. What am I doing wrong? I've tried setting them as read only and mandatory on the template and they still don't populate the checks in the boxes.

***updated with correct code below**

```
       $sellerTabs = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs();
                 $count_fields = 0;

                 foreach ($fields_data as $key => $field_value) {
                     //echo $field_value."\n";
                     $seller_address[$count_fields] = new 
                     \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Text(["tab_label" => $key, 
                     "value" => $field_value]);
                       $count_fields++;



                 } 
                 $tab_group = $_REQUEST["group"];
                 $sellerTabs = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs();
                 $count_checks = 0;
                    foreach ($checks_data as $key => $check_value) {
                    //echo $check_value."\n";                                                                
                     $seller_checks[$count_checks]= new 
                   DocuSign\eSign\Model\Checkbox(["tab_label" => $key, 
                   "selected" => 
                   $check_value,"Checkbox_Group"=>$tab_group]);
                     $count_checks++;
                    }
                  //file_put_contents("create_event.log",   
                  "json_decode($checks, true);" ,FILE_APPEND;   
                 "json_decode($fields, true);", FILE_APPEND);
                   //exit();

                 $sellerTabs->setTextTabs($seller_address);
                 $sellerTabs->setCheckboxTabs($seller_checks);

                 $envelop_definition = new 
                 DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition();
                 $b_roles = array();

                  //exit();
                // echo $roles_data;
                 foreach ($roles_data as $role_data) {
                    // echo $role_data;
                     $data = explode("|", $role_data);
                     $role_data = new  DocuSign\eSign\Model\TemplateRole();
                     $role_data->setName($data[0]);
                     $role_data->setEmail($data[1]);
                     $role_data->setRoleName($data[2]);
                     $role_data->setRoutingOrder($data[3]);
                     $role_data->setTabs($sellerTabs);

                     //echo $role_data;
                     array_push($b_roles, $role_data);
                 }
                  //var_dump($b_roles);
                 /*echo "<pre>";
                 print_r($_REQUEST["templateID"]);
                 exit();*/
                  //   $envelop_definition- 
                     >setTemplateRoles(array($sellerRole /, 
                        $templateRole3/));
```

Comment: I figured it out

Comment: Mind posting what was wrong as an answer for future reference?